# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rules - Buy One Product Get Another Product Free

Tags: magento

is it possible to set a rule so that buying a product A will automatically get another product B free? A and B are different products.

Thank you.

p.s. I'm using the enterprise edition v1.13

Answer (score 0):

David, try this url http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-setup-buy-x-get-y-free . I feel it will resolve your issue.

if you want to different product as free than have to add rules and I feel you have to use SKU for that purpose. You can go to admin->attributes->Manage Attributes and click on sku to edit. change Use for Promo Rule Conditions to Yes and save it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I think it only apply to the same product, e.g. But 2 product A and get 1 product A free. What I want is getting another kind of product free of charge. How to set the rule in such case?

Comment: if you want to different product as free than have to add rules and I feel you have to use SKU for that purpose. You can go to admin->attributes->Manage Attributes and click on sku to edit. change Use for Promo Rule Conditions to Yes and save it and create rules like if SKU is...

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do out of the box in Magento. Out of the box, Magento only allows BOGO discounts on the same items. That is, you can set up a rule that discounts the second exact same product in the customer's cart, but not a rule that discounts a product from another category.

To set up a BOGO cart rule for products from another category, you need a third party extension. One of the extensions that implement this functionality is [Additional Promotions](https://www.mexbs.com/additional-promotions-magento2-extension).

**Disclaimer: I am the CEO of the company that developed this extension.**